# complement of concatenate languages equal to complements concatenated?

Tags: formal-languages, computability

please help me with this one.
(a formal answer would be much appreciated)

∀L1, L2 ⊆ Σ:

(L1 · L2)^c = L1^c · L2^c

when · represents concatination and ^c the complement language.
do not know if languages are regular.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Let $L_1=L_2=\{a\}$ (that is the language consisting only of the sentence $a$).

Then $\epsilon\in L_1^c$ and $aa\in L_2^c$.

Since $\epsilon\cdot aa=aa$, $aa\in L_1^c\cdot L_2^c$.

But $aa$ is certainly not in $(L_1L_2)^c$.